# My Laptop does not switch to wired connection when put into a docking station. Is this normal?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, lan, docking-station

I have a Dell 6430u laptop for my job.  I usually work off wireless, however when I place my laptop BACK on my docking station, it does not recognize my LAN network.   I continues to use wireless.  Is this normal?  If not, how can I correct it.

Answer (score 3):

The wireless adapter will not be automatically disabled when the computer is put back in the station. However it will make both the wireless and wired adapters active.

Comment: Thanks for the quick repsonse.  I really appreciate it.  So will I need to manually disable the wireless connection everytime the 6430u is placed on the docking station?

Comment: @Michael no, they are both active, just don't worry about it.